# What coverage does the Nokia SDK 2.0 have?

Tags: sdk, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I am attempting to develop for as many feature phone devices as possible, my question is, if I opt to use the Nokia SDK 2.0 - what sort of device coverage can I expect? Will the SDK work with old devices (5 years +)?

Currently I am using the LWUIT 1.5 jar to manage UI but as it is no longer supported it seems like a logical move to go to the Nokia SDK.

Is this a wise choice if maximum device coverage is desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the question is about the LWUIT supposer with nokia devices, I suppose the answer could be found from: [Github project for LWUIT for S40](https://github.com/nokia-developer/lwuit-for-series-40), it states **"LWUIT for Series 40 has been developed and tested with Nokia SDK 1.1 and 2.0 for Java and it can be used for applications targeted at Series 40 5th Edition and newer devices with both keypad and touch user interface"**